# delete row(s) from ng-grid table from button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I have a table with ng-grid, and the problem is that i'm not sure how to collect the selected row(s) id or variable to pass into my delete function.

here is a quick mockup of what i'm trying to do

http://plnkr.co/edit/zy653RrqHmBiRJ7xDHlV?p=preview

the following code is from my html, a clickable delete button that takes in 2 parameters, the array of checkbox ids and the index at the corresponding table. This delete method was obtained from this tutorial : http://alexpotrykus.com/blog/2013/12/07/angularjs-with-rails-4-part-1/

```
 <div class="btn-group">
  <button class="my-btn btn-default button-row-provider-medical-services" ng-click="deleteProviderMedicalService([], $index)">Delete</button>
  </button>
</div>
 <div class="gridStyle ngGridTable" ng-grid="gridOptions">
 </div>
```

The following code  grabs the json data from a url, queries it and returns it. It also contains the delete function that gets called from the controller in the html page.

```
app.factory('ProviderMedicalService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
function ProviderMedicalService() {
this.service = $resource('/api/provider_medical_services/:providerMedicalServiceId', {providerMedicalServiceId: '@id'});
};

ProviderMedicalService.prototype.all = function() {
return this.service.query();
};


ProviderMedicalService.prototype.delete = function(providerId) {
this.service.remove({providerMedicalServiceId: providerId});
};

return new ProviderMedicalService;
}]);
```

The following is my controller(not everything, just the most important bits). $scope.provider_medical_services gets the json data and puts it into the ng-grid gridOptions.
After reading the ng-grid docs, i must somehow pass the checkbox ids from the selectedItems array and pass it into html doc to the delete function. Or, i'm just doing this completely wrong, as i hacked this together. Solutions and suggestions are greatly appreciated

```
  (function() {
  app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'ProviderMedicalService', '$resource', '$modal', function($scope, ProviderMedicalService, $resource, $modal) {


 var checkBoxCellTemplate = '<div class="ngSelectionCell"><input tabindex="-1" class="ngSelectionCheckbox" type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.selected" /></div>';

 $scope.provider_medical_services = ProviderMedicalService.all();

 $scope.deleteProviderMedicalService = function(ids,idx) {
  $scope.provider_medical_services.splice(idx, 1);
  return ProviderMedicalService.delete(ids);
 };

 $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
     {
        cellTemplate: checkBoxCellTemplate,
        showSelectionCheckbox: true
      },{
        field: 'name',
        displayName: 'CPT Code/Description'
      },{
        field: 'cash_price',
      displayName: 'Cash Price'
      },{
        field: 'average_price',
        displayName: 'Average Price'
      },

     ],
     data: 'provider_medical_services',
     selectedItems: []

   };
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest option is pass an (array index) as data-id to your dom, which u can pick it from there.

{{$index}} is a variable you can use in ng-repeat

======= ignore what i said above, since i normaly writes my own custom stuff ======

I just had a look at ng-grid, i took their example. i've added a delete all selected function, as well as someone elses delete current row function ( these is pure angular way ) to see the code, hover over the top right corner < edit in jsbin >

http://jsbin.com/huyodove/1/

Honestsly i don't like it this way, you would be better off use something like lodash to manage your arrays and do your own custom grid. Using foreach to find the row index isn't good performance.

In their doc, it says you can change the row template, and which you should, so you can add the {{index}} to that row, and filter your data through that index rather which is a little bit better. anyway beware of deleting cells after you have filter your table.

Comment: are you saying use ng-repeat in ng-grid in the html page?

Comment: the delete all selected, is not working as intended?

Comment: it doesn't work? works for me, what it matters is the part, where  you find all the selected rows from angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.selectedItems, (the last function in the code) than you look through your $scope.data array to find match and grab that index,  so you can remove it off your $scope.data with splice. only thing i could think off it might not work is it will offset the index on every splice, so it need to remove by reverse, but the example i wrote seems working so it doesnt need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get much your question, but you can access to selectedItems of ng-grid as following: **$scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.selectedItems** (see ng-grid API for more information, but technically this array holds the list of selected items in multiple mode - or only one item in single mode)

For your case, the deleteAll() function could be someething like this:

```
$scope.deleteAll = function() {
  $scope.myData = [];
}
```

The delete() function which delete selected items can be:

```
$scope.delete = function() {
  $.each($scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.selectedItems, function(index, selectedItem) {
    //remove the selected item from 'myData' - it is 2-ways binding to any modification to myData will be reflected in ng-grid table
    //you could check by either name or unique id of item
  });
}
```